What is Configuration Space as described in Bohmian Mechanics?
Are the configuration spaces necessary in Bohmian mechanics simply a mathematical abstraction that is not directly related to any set of dimensions "classically" experienced? Can they be directly turned into something more physically intuitive beyond that? What about the simplest case of one partice with a 3D configuration space--is that space the same as 3D space (x,y,z)?

Yes, if there is only one particle. Then configuration space $(\mathbb R^3)^n$ coincides with $\mathbb R$. However, this coincidence can be misleading since it looks as if wave functions are fields in physical space. This is, however, not the case.
It is not clear what you mean by classical experience (should this be contrasted with some other kind of experience?).
Meaning of configuration space
The configuration space in Bohmian mechanics is not used as an abstract mathematical object, but it is connected to the theory of what the physical world consists of. I.e., in Bohmian world, there are particles that move in physical $3$-space according to the law.
$$
\qquad\ \frac {\mathrm{d} \vec Q_i(t)} {\mathrm{d}t} = \frac {\hbar} {m_i} \operatorname {Im} \frac {\vec \nabla_i \psi} {\psi}
$$.
To some degree, this is comparable to the difference between Hamiltonian mechanics on a symplectic manifold $(\mathcal M, \omega)$ and Newtonian mechanics. The former is a mathematical dynamical system on $(\mathcal M, \omega)$. The latter supplements the abstract system with a theory of a physical world. I.e., in Newtonian mechanics, the symplectic manifold represents the phase space of particles. In particular the point $(\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n, \vec p_1, \dots, \vec p_n) \in \mathbb R^{6n})$ has the physical meaning of $n$ particles at the positions $\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n$ with momentum $\vec p_1, \dots, \vec p_n$.
Bohmian mechanics is different to classical Newtonian mechanics in the fact that it is a first-order theory. Therefore, the momenta $\vec p_1, \dots, \vec p_n$ are not relevant for the EoMs. Configuration space is just the position part of phase space.
Concerning Experience
Bohmian mechanics is not a theory about experience or human perception, etc. The configuration space does not represent the dimensions of our experience or our visual space (Anschaung). It represents degrees of freedom of physical entities.
Nonetheless, statements about experience can be derived from Bohmian mechanics, e.g., by analyzing the behaviour of a collection of particles that constitute a macroscopic observer or apparatus.
Wave function of a single particle
In Bohmian mechanics, there is only one universal wave function $\Psi: \mathbb R^{3n} \to \mathbb C$ that always evolves according to the Schrödinger equation. However, you can define a conditional wave function for a single particle by plugging in all other positions.
$$
\psi_{\text{cond}\, }{}_t(\vec x_n) = \mathcal N \Psi_t(\vec Q_1(t), \dots, \vec Q_{n-1}(t), \vec x_n).
$$
Here $\mathcal N$ is a normalization constant. $\psi_{\text{cond}\, }{}_t$ is defined on $3D$ space. Note, that $\psi_{\text{cond}\, }{}_t$ is derived from $\Psi_t$, not the other way. You cannot derive the universal wave function $\Psi$ from all the single-particle wave functions.

Great answer!  One other important point:  We also use configuration spaces in classical theories (namely classical statistical mechanics).  The central difference is that in those classical theories, "reality" takes the form of a single point in that space.  (Even if we don't know it, there is one actual configuration.). In quantum theory (not just in Bohmian mechanics, but also in conventional QM which uses configuration-space wavefunctions!) the state of the system is not a point but a function on configuration space.  This is an enormous conceptual difference.
